# Principal Value of another integral

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
\phi(x)=1\text{ if } |x|<1,
$$
and
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(1+(|x|^2-1)^{4})^\frac{n+ps}{8}}, \text{if }|x|\geq 1.
$$
Let $\delta>0$ be  small so that the following Taylor series expansion holds:
$$
\phi(y)=\phi(x)+\nabla\phi\cdot(y-x)+(y-x)^tD^2\phi(z)(y-x)
$$
for some $z\in B_1(x)$.
Then I want to check the Principal Value of the following quantities:
$$
(i)\int_{|x-y|\leq\delta}\frac{|\nabla\phi(x)\cdot(y-x)|^{p-2}\nabla\phi(x)\cdot(y-x)}{|x-y|^{n+ps}}\,dy
$$
$$
(ii)\int_{|x-y|\leq\delta}\frac{|\nabla\phi(x)\cdot(y-x)|^{p-2}(y-x)^{t}D^2\phi(z)(y-x)}{|x-y|^{n+ps}}\,dy
$$
and
$$
(iii)\int_{|x-y|\leq\delta}\frac{\nabla\phi(x)\cdot(y-x)\{(y-x)^{t}D^2\phi(z)(y-x)\}^{p-2}}{|x-y|^{n+ps}}\,dy.
$$
Can someone help me with this one. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried to correct the misspelled title, and the robot said that there was already a question "Principal Value of an integral".  So I changed the title a bit to make it unique and correctly spelled.

Comment: Thank you very much.